# Is taking advantage of optional parameter edge cases to force implementations of ToString via an interface abuse of the language?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have an interface `IKey` which I want to have a method which will return the key as a string.  We looked at having a method like this:

```
String GetAsString();
```

which would return the string representation, but would have liked to be able to declare `ToString()` again in the interface to force implementers to implement it, but it doesn't force them to as they have an implementation inherited from `Object`.  This was suggested:

```
public interface IKey
{
    string ToString(string dummyParameter=null);
}
```

this forces an implementation of the method in any implementing class, but due to the [way that optional parameters work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/16/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-three.aspx) callers do not need to provide a value for this, and you ensure that any calls to the `ToString()` method on objects which are either cast as the interface `IKey` or the implementing class will always call the class implementation and not the `Object` implementation.

In the implementations we can just ignore the `dummyParameter` and return what we want, safe in the knowledge that calling `ToString()` will always actually call `ToString(null)`.

Now this feels wrong all over to me, but at the same time it does have something quite nice about it.  It is almost exactly the same as having a method `GetAsString()` as this could only be called on the `IKey` interface and derived classes except that it looks like the more natural `ToString()` method that we want to use and that we are able to force the implementing of in the child class.

Having said that the dummy parameter which is not used feels wrong.

So is this horrendous?  Or great?

And is this question appropriate for SO or should it be on Programmers?

*Examples*

```
public class Key :IKey 
    { 
        public string ToString(string abc = null) 
        { 
            return "100"; 
        } 
    }

Key key = new Key ();
Trace.WriteLine (key.ToString());
Trace.WriteLine (key.ToString(null));
Trace.WriteLine (key.ToString("ac"));
Trace.WriteLine (((object)key).ToString());
```

output:

```
100
100
100
Blah.Tests.Key
```

Comment: Does it have to be named ToString()?  I don't see the advantage of naming it this.  Anything that would attempt to call ToString() on it will just use object's implementation of it, right?  I mean it seems to me like you are going through an extra hoop here when you could just name it something else and get the same functionality.  I could be wrong.  Just my thoughts.

Comment: @Akron that's exactly the point, anything that calls ToString() on it **doesn't** use the Object implementation, it uses the class implementation (except if the instance is explictly cast as Object.  I'll add some examples to make it clear

Comment: Eric Lippert has written about this particular corner case and the things you need to consider with optional parameters on interfaces: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/09/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-one.aspx

Comment: @JoshuaRodgers thanks, that series of articles was linked to in the question

Comment: I don't see the problem with GetAsString. Anyway I probably would create a string property getter called Key returning the key as string.

Comment: @SamHolder Sorry, I didn't catch the link when I read through.

Comment: It doesn't accomplish anything.  The programmer will mutter wtf and return base.ToString().  Use another name.

Comment: I have a feeling that the name `IKey` is wrong, and that the implementing classes are not keys, but objects that have a key.  That way, if the interface is called `IKeyed` or `IIndexed`, then you can feel more comfortable with a member `string Key { get; }`.  I hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view such `ToString()` method in a custom interface slightly messed up things because a custom interface exposed a method with standard and well known name `ToString()`.

I prefer something more straightforward and obvious like:

```
string KeyText { get; }
```

OR method

```
string ConvertKeyToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're using an interface where you should be using an abstract class.  The class below explicitly requires descendants to have implemented `ToString`.

```
abstract class X
{
    public abstract override string ToString();
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks.  I'm aware of this option, but, for arguments sake lets say I want to avoid abstract classes and program only to interfaces.

Comment: Completely agree. I would give a +2 if I could :)

Comment: @Sam: I think this might feel like a 'weird' way to use an interface to you because it's not the most appropriate programming construct for your problem. Austin hit the nail on the head that the problem you identified is best suited to an abstract base class.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer already suggests the abstract class, which I think is the best option for this.

The idea of adding a ToString with a default parameter to the interface doesn't work too well in practive. The overload resolution will find the ToString without parameters when called without parameters (which, I must say, seems intuitive). Consider the output of this program:

```
void Main()
{   
    Console.WriteLine(new Key().ToString());
}

public interface IKey 
{
    string ToString(string dummy = null);
}

class Key : IKey 
{   
    public string ToString(string dummy) 
    {
        return "myspecialKey";
    }
}
```

This outputs the object.ToString() implementation. Therefore, if you are restricted to use an interface, I would name the method something else than ToString().

Comment: whist you have a point, if the API expects and deals with IKey everywhere then we will never call the Object.ToString() implementation, but any implementations of IKey would have to provide a ToString() implementation

Comment: Yes, but that also means that the solution robustness depends on Key being typed as `Key` or `IKey`. This could lead to interesting bugs ... I think I'd rather depend on developers remembering to override object.ToString() or naming the method something else.

Comment: indeed.  This provides one of the more compelling arguments against the idea for me.  I much prefer the new name approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Re-purposing**

(IMO) -`ToString()` already has a very well-defined purpose and meaning.  It may be convenient for you to hijack it based on the name, but by saying it's required you're re-purposing something that you shouldn't.

The answer is to have your own separate method, the initial idea.  Anything else means all the .NET documentation about `ToString()` becomes 'wrong'.

E.g. the Tag property being an object on many UI controls.  It could be that you want to 'tag' controls in some kind of control gallery.  Just because the name fits, and the type fits, doesn't mean the meaning is the same and you can grab hold of it and re-purpose it.

**Naming**

I would also suggest considering changing your interface name; unless the implementers are actually keys?  I get the impression that they are simply 'keyed', or have some key associated with them.  In which case, `IKeyed`, `IIndexed` or something might be better.  Then a `string Key { get; }` becomes more attractive.  Perhaps it's just the naming that's the issue here.?

Comment: We are not repurposing we want the keys to return a sensible value for ToString, but would like any implementation of IKey to be forced to implement something sensible.  The docs state 'Returns a string that represents the current object.' which is exactly what we want to enforce.  As for the names, the interface is used by objects which are keys for different types of things (EntityKey, EntityTypeKey, NetworkElementKey, NetworkElementTypeKey etc)

Comment: So can you confirm that the objects implementing IKey are in fact keys themselves, and not just 'something with a key'?

Comment: yes the objects implementing IKey are actual objects which act as keys.  So an `Entity` has a `Key` property which returns an `IEntityKey` which implements `IKey`

Comment: If the object itself is a key, wouldn't it be better implementing `IComparable`, a decent `GetHashCode` and `Equals`?  Why have an object that's an `IKey`, already returned from another object, where all the key-like duties are then delegated to yet another object in the graph, a `string`?  I would strongly suggest that the `IKey` object is the key, and not another `string` dangling off it.  If there are operations not worth repeating across classes, use an abstract `KeyBase` class instead.

Comment: @SamHolder:  I think you're taking liberty on what is required of a string that `represents the current object`.  I have no idea if 100 is a long, int32, float, etc.  What you have given me is the current object's value, not a representation of the object itself. There's a property, and there's a property value (I know that's not **exactly** what we're discussing, but close enough).  HUGE difference.  It will be seriously bad ju-ju if I ask for one and receive the other. The same way that I will be unamused if I ask ToString() to tell me about the object I have and it gives me a value instead.

Comment: My point being, someone will implement an `IKey`, but then won't be able to specify whether two keys are equal.  They're given the impression they can implement a key's behavior, but in reality all they can do is return a `string` and some other part of the system will dictate what happens from there.

Comment: @PeteM, sorry the example above was just for the purposes of the example, the actual implementation would likely return the object type + anything that makes the key unique (which my contain other keys).  Basically enough info to be able to reparse and recreate the key.

Comment: Hmmmm, that makes it sound like you're trying to come up with a novel approach to serializing an object...  There are easier ways to do that. ;o)   You're still giving me something I don't expect.  I would still be decidedly unamused with such a result from ToString().

Comment: @PeteM yeah I know.  I'm not a fan of the idea myself, just trying to play devils advocate.  The approach felt wrong, but I couldn't articulate why.  The answers here have cleared things up a lot for me.

Comment: If the proposed solution is "hijacking", so are other implementations in the .NET framework that provide overloads for .ToString() that accept parameters.

Comment: I agree Eric :) But they're a far cry from this one, which changes the contract of the method too, i.e. it must be implemented, and has a hidden parameter in most cases..

Answer (score 1):

I would call this abuse, because of the problem you hint at right here:

> ...and you ensure that any calls to the ToString() method on objects which are either cast as the interface IKey or the implementing class will always call the class implementation and not the Object implementation.

Consider the following code:

```
IKey someKey = ...;
string keyAsString = someKey.ToString();
object someKeyAsObject = (object)someKey;
string keyAsString2 = someKeyAsObject.ToString();
```

Anybody looking at this code would assume that `keyAsString` and `keyAsString2` are the same. However, these would be calling *different* methods that may have *different* behavior. Eek!

Answer (score 1):

Horrendous, if I have to pick just one word...  Confused and suspicious would more accurately describe my reaction if I came across this in the wild.

I try to follow one rule above all others when designing API's:  Do not surprise the developer.

This would most certainly be a surprise.  It precludes the use of the *expected* output and usage of `ToString()` without special effort.  The fact that there's no indication of the special effort required would be the "surprise" bit.  The default implementation of `ToString()` ends up getting used more often than I would have expected.  I would avoid prohibiting or distorting its usage unless I had no other reasonable way to solve an issue.

I don't think this would be "more natural" than a well named method/property that isn't already a member of `object`.

Comment: double.ToString() (among several other examples) provide overloads of .ToString()...

Comment: True, however I would expect those overloads to function the same way every time I use them as documented.  I would be annoyed if they suddenly behaved differently.  If you're asserting that since the BCL provides overloads for something like `ToString()` that it is intended and expected for developers to hijack one of those overloads and completely change its purpose, I strongly disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this.  What about having the interface inherit IFormattable?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.aspx

I haven't done this myself so I might be wrong, but that seems to enable use of a format parameter for a `ToString` method for your interface.  Note you are still not alterring the parameterless `ToString`, which I agree with others should not be done in an interface, but instead you make use of `ToString(string format, IFormatProvider provider)` with a recognizable format input that basically means "give me a description of this object in the context that it implements IWhatever".  Obviously each implemented classes will need to code the method, but that is only proper.